# using sed and tr instead of awk in linux

Tags: linux

```
#!
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) no[$i]++
} END{ for (word in no) printf "%-15s%5d\n", word, no[word]
}' $*
```

this is the description of the command which shows words and their repetitions so i wanted to use sed and or tr instead of awk and I also wanted it to ignore punctuation and be case-insensitive

Comment: And why would you want that? `sed` cannot count. So if there is a work-around then it is probably very ugly. This seems useless to me.

Comment: it is for a homework where i have to use this using sed or tr

Comment: `tr` doesn't have the functionality of `awk`, either. It can only translate and delete characters.

Comment: What kind of homework is that if not even I have an idea how to do that... Is there anything you are not telling us? Are the words and their maximum number known?

Comment: I suggest speaking to your instructor and informing him or her that neither `sed` nor `tr` have the functionality to do what is required. It's a useless exercise and would be similar to requiring the use of `cut` to rename files.

Comment: You could use `sed` and/or `tr` to convert free-form text into *input suitable for counting* by `sort` and `uniq` for example - perhaps that is the intent of the exercise?

Comment: yes that is... we are supposed to use sort and uniq too

Comment: There is a book file and the output after using awk is each word and their counts so we are supposed to use sed and/or tr to get the same result by using also count and uniq

Comment: It would have been helpful to mention that sort and uniq could be in the mix too. tr can make a word list (convert space and tab to newline, and use the -s (squeeze) option to get rid or empty lines. Use another tr to delete things that are not alphanumeric. Use sort to get the the words in order, which enables uniq to count them, and use sed to rearrange the fields for printing. Five commands in a pipeline, five man pages to get to grips with.

Comment: i have done the first one which is making them one word per line. can you help me with the next four steps\

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have already, and what it does. The tr command only does one thing at a time. So you will now need three consecutive tr commands: (1) to remove punctuation; (2) to lowercase the letters; (3) to make it word-per-line. And then (4) sort and (5) uniq. I'm stuck on the explicit formatting -- 15 columns for the word and then a decimal count. None of the tools mentioned will do that, but a shell loop and a printf, or a sed and expand, would. Are those permitted?

Answer (score 0):

If the words and their maximum number are known then it is indeed possible to "count" with only `tr` and `sed`. It's no fun, though, and thus I do it for one word and no more than 4 occurrances only.

The input file:

```
foo bar
foo bar baz
bar baz
foo
```

The `sed` nightmare:

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' <input |
  sed -r ': start; s/((^|[^%]))foo\b/\1%foo/; T end; s/%foo/%%foo/; t start; '\
': end; : delstart; s/(foo.*) %foo\b/\1/g; t delstart' |
  tr ' ' '\n' |
  sed -r 's/^%%%%/4 /; s/^%%%/3 /; s/^%%/2 /; s/^%/1 /'

4 foo
bar
bar
baz
bar
baz
```

Does not work if the "counting character" (here: `%`) appears directly in front of the word.

Comment: the words are not known. they are just words of a long novel where the novel is changed into one word per line so sed and tr will identify all the words used with their repetition